# How to make previously active application focused on workspace change

Tags: workspaces

I am using Ubuntu 23.04 with default settings. I have enabled workspaces with **Fixed number of workspaces** and **workspaces on primary display only**. Whenever I switch workspaces the previously active window isn't focused.

For example I have terminal open on Workspace 1 and I change workspace and then move back to Workspace 1, but now terminal isn't active and typing anything does not appear on the terminal. I have to explicitly focus by mouse click.

Is there a way to focus last active window on a workspace on workspace change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I read that this is some kind of bug, and it is partially solved by setting the "Switch Focus Type", in the "focus follows the mouse" mode.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment pointed me in the right direction. I didn't know about "focus follows the mouse" mode. It is not perfect but it works.